# Ordered List is not working as expected with ng-repeat in IE

Tags: angularjs

```
<ol>
<li>Please find things here..</li>
<span ng-repeat="list in vm.ListObject  | unique:'value'| orderBy">
<li>Search for "{{list.value}}"</li>
<li>Proceed</li>
</span>
<li>Click "Checkout" and complete the requi`enter code here`red fields</li>
<li>Click "Submit Requests"</li>
</ol>
```

" It is working fine in Chrome.
    But not working as expected in IE. The list is starting from span tag again"

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to `<ol>` elements requiring `<li>` children. You're code is trying to render a `<span>` as a child of an `<ol>` to faciliate the `ng-repeat` - IE will probably fail to handle this as gracefully as Chrome.

If you're using angular 1.2+, you can replace the `ng-repeat` directive with the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives to work around this issue:

```
<ol>
  <!-- add ng-repeat-start -->
  <li ng-repeat-start="list in vm.ListObject  | unique:'value'| orderBy">
  Please find things here..
  </li>

  <li>Search for "{{list.value}}"</li>
  <li>Proceed</li>

  <!-- add ng-repeat-end -->
  <li ng-repeat-end>
  Click "Checkout" and complete the requi`enter code here`red fields
  </li>

  <li>Click "Submit Requests"</li>
</ol>
```

Here's [a link to the documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) for more information on this